# How to change the datatype of hive from string to multi-dimension array to split the column correctly

Tags: hive

I have a hive table like:

```
+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| DEVTYPE  |                POINTS                                                                        |
+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Array    | [['1538006400', '629928.0625'], ['1538611200', '629928.0625'], ['1539216000', '629928.0625']]|
| Array    | [['1541030400', '629928.0625'], ['1541635200', '629928.0625'], ['1542240000', '629928.0625']]|       
| Array    | [['1544054400', '629928.0625'], ['1544659200', '629928.0625'], ['1545264000', '629928.125']] |
| Array    | [['1547078400', '629928.0625'], ['1547683200', '629928.0625'], ['1548288000', '629928.0625']]|
| Array    | [['1550102400', '629928.0625'], ['1550707200', '629928.125'], ['1551312000', '629928.0625']] |
+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But when I describe the table I found the POINTS columns is having datatype as a string.
I want to convert into an array type so that I could split it into several columns to analyze the data correctly.

I tried to alter by changing column data type but it's giving me an error,

```
alter table my_table change points points array<double>;
```

I tried to use a different approach like:

```
alter table my_table change points points array<array<double>>;
```

I know the above command is wrong but still, I want to give it a try but I got this error in both the case. The error message:

```
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Unable to alter table. The following columns have types incompatible with the existing columns in their respective positions :
points (state=08S01,code=1)
```

Any idea how to solve this issue and how can I make this column compatible like an array to split into different columns.
Any help I will appreciate.

Comment: output of `show create table points`  please?

Comment: CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `my_table`( 
  `points` string COMMENT 'from deserializer',  
  `devtype` string COMMENT 'from deserializer');

Comment: ok let me look into this later today and let you know :)

Comment: Hi @smart_coder actually this ingestion is made by automated table ingestion command, we flat the JSON using python pandas and then we ingest but pandas normalize the JSON by making each column as object type or string type. That's why that automated ingestion command creating this query for ingesting data.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will be much happier if there is any workaround in this.

Comment: no worries, we will handle this in hive query itself and write it to a another table

Comment: Yeah, that's really great!!

Comment: updated the answer! please check if this helps!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219924/discussion-between-sathya-and-mohammad-rijwan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below approach might be helpful to you, Note: (cast to double if needed)

```
CREATE TABLE my_table2( devtype string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
points array<array<string>> COMMENT 'from deserializer') row format delimited 
fields terminated by ':' stored as textfile;

insert into table my_table values( "Array","[['1538006400', '629928.0625'],
 ['1538611200', '629928.0625'], ['1539216000', '629928.0625']]");

insert into table my_table2 select devtype, array(
array(trim(regexp_replace(split(points,",")[0],"\\[|\\[\\[\\'|\\'|\\]|\\]\\]",'')),
trim(regexp_replace(split(points,",")[1],"\\[|\\[\\[\\'|\\'|\\]|\\]\\]",''))), 
array(trim(regexp_replace(split(points,",")[2],"\\[|\\[\\[\\'|\\'|\\]|\\]\\]",'')),
trim(regexp_replace(split(points,",")[3],"\\[|\\[\\[\\'|\\'|\\]|\\]\\]",''))), 
array(trim(regexp_replace(split(points,",")[4],"\\[|\\[\\[\\'|\\'|\\]|\\]\\]",'')),
trim(regexp_replace(split(points,",")[5],"\\[|\\[\\[\\'|\\'|\\]|\\]\\]",'')))) 
from my_table_tmp;


hive> select devtype, points[0][0],points[1][0],points[2][0] from my_table2;
OK
Array   1538006400      1538611200      1539216000

hive> select devtype, points[0][1],points[1][1],points[2][1] from my_table2;
OK
Array   629928.0625     629928.0625     629928.0625
```